# Voltage multiplier

Tags: voltage, capacitor, multiplier

please be patient as I am not a electrician/electronic engineer. I am wanting to make a negative ion generator to attempt to make a powder coating gun, I know they are cheap but I like to build for cheaper.

Now I have looked at the basics and understand it to a certain  degree, using the Villard cascade method I will be able to achieve a high voltage, assuming AC input is 240v with 8 sections I should be able to get 60kv.

Now my questions are, towards the end of the generator the voltage is very high, will I need capacitors rated to 60kv as I can't seem to find them.

Also it would be handy to have two different voltage setting, installing a switch between the last two sets means I can cut out the last set and half the voltage, however will it work or just melt the switch/give me a hell of a shock?

And help is appreciated, thanks Chris.

Comment: If a ready made powder coating gun is cheap I would recommend buying one in stead of playing around with something that can be very dangerous and potentially kill you.

Comment: improperly designed high voltage circuits can start producing ozone, which can be toxic

Comment: I understand your concerns but if wire g is done right it would be impossible to produce ozone this way, here is the link to the web site where the generator is made, obviously this is for air purification not powder coating. It just seems to me that his g that many capacitors should cause the one at the end to explode with excessive voltage. Although the current will be very low.

Comment: @ChrisWhite If you need to ask about these things, you shouldn't be working with these things. Imagine a doctor asking another doctor in front of his/her patient the following question: "Is the aorta the big tube leaving the heart? Or is it the valves in the heart? I'm supposed to fix the aorta in this patient".  Right now we are the patients, you are the doctor. We are scared of what you might do. - Don't work with dangerous things you.... don't have enough knowledge about. Well, not my problem if you die prematurely.

Answer (score 1):

The capacitors (and diodes and switches) used do not have to withstand the final voltage of the multiplier circuit, they only have to be rated for the relative voltage difference of the adjacent components.

Answer (score 1):

> Now I have looked at the basics and understand it to a certain degree,
>   using the Villard cascade method I will be able to achieve a high
>   voltage, assuming AC input is 240v with 8 sections I should be able to
>   get 60kv.

No, you don't get \$240\times 2^8\$ volts (61.44 kV).

With 8 sections you get 8 x 2 x 240 volts (3840 volts).

[Wikipedia for the Cockcroft Walton generator (an alias for Villard)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator) says: -

> The no-load output voltage is twice the peak input voltage multiplied
>   by the number of stages N or equivalently the peak-to-peak input
>   voltage swing (Vpp) times the number of stages

You can always use a free sim tool and prove that to yourself. There are websites that claim that each stage is a doubler but those web sites are brain muddled.

> Now my questions are, towards the end of the generator the voltage is
>   very high, will I need capacitors rated to 60kv as I can't seem to
>   find them.

The capacitor rating is the same throughout but, if you did build a multiplier having many, many stages, beyond about 5 kV I would recommend an oil bath for those stages and significant clearances.

> Also it would be handy to have two different voltage setting,
>   installing a switch between the last two sets means I can cut out the
>   last set and half the voltage, however will it work or just melt the
>   switch/give me a hell of a shock?

That's a foolish idea given your voltage expactations. Just reduce the 240 volts input with a variac.

Comment: Thanks Andy, as you explain it I don't understand the basics, I was reading online and that did say every section doubles, I see it's not so easy to achieve the voltage I require, the other method people use is coils, I'm not even going to think about that I'll just buy a gun, again thanks for your helpful input. Here is the web site responsible for making it look so easy....www.google.co.uk/amp/www.instructables.com/id/How-to-Make-a-Negative-Ion-air-ionizer/%3famp_page=true

Comment: @ChrisWhite I did have to make a 50 kV x-ray supply once but I used a transformer to get me up to a voltage of about 2 kV RMS (5.6 kVp-p) at 50 kHz. Above that ferrite transformers do get problematic and so I used a cockcroft walton multiplier to give me the x10 uplift.